how to access other fields of the model in custom serializer in gorm
I've a custom type field in the model. That custom type field has custom serializer. I need to access other field (type) from the model so I can do de-serialization based on that.
Don't know how to access that field, because value can be string, int, float and bool. Type field has the info what it need to be de-serialized. like if type == int, I need to de-serialize that dbValue (which always comes as string as db field is text) into int.
type Setting struct {
    ID    uint                     `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Type  string                   `json:"type" gorm:"type:varchar(100); not null;"`
    Value serializers.SettingValue `json:"value" gorm:"type:text;"`
}

Following is the custom serializer
type SettingValue struct {
    Val any `json:"val"`
}

// Scan implements schema.SerializerInterface (db out)
func (sv *SettingValue) Scan(ctx context.Context, field *schema.Field, dst reflect.Value, dbValue interface{}) (err error) {

    // 1. find out the type

    fmt.Printf("dxx %#v %T \n", dbValue) // dxx []byte{0x54, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74} []uint8
    // Q1: how to access model.Type field?
    // Q2: Why dbValue is []uint8?


    // 2. decode value base on the type field


    return
}

func (*SettingValue) Value(ctx context.Context, field *schema.Field, dst reflect.Value, fieldValue interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
    // r is raw string (not base64)

    return r, nil
}

Very new at Go, Any help or direction I'll highly appreciate.
